# Using a variable to retrieve image from My.Resources

Tags: vb.net, variables, picturebox, my.resources

Here is my code (everything is pre-declared for use in the entire form's class):

```
 Private Sub Pokedex_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    IntPokemonCounter = 0
    Dim fileReader As System.IO.StreamReader
    fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("TotalPokemonNames.txt")
    While (IntPokemonCounter < 51)
        PokémonName(IntPokemonCounter) = fileReader.ReadLine()
        listPokemon.Items.Add(PokémonName(IntPokemonCounter))
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(PokémonNumber(IntPokemonCounter) + "" + PokémonName(IntPokemonCounter))
        'MsgBox("The " & IntPokemonCounter + 1 & "th pokemon is " & PokémonName(IntPokemonCounter))
        IntPokemonCounter += 1
    End While
    IntPokemonCounter = 0
    While (IntPokemonCounter < 51)
        PokémonNumber(IntPokemonCounter) = IntPokemonCounter + 1
        If PokémonNumber.Length = 1 Then
            PokémonNumber(IntPokemonCounter) = "00" + (IntPokemonCounter + 1)
        ElseIf PokémonNumber.Length = 2 Then
            PokémonNumber(IntPokemonCounter) = "0" + (IntPokemonCounter + 1)
        End If
        IntPokemonCounter += 1
    End While
    IntPokemonCounter = 0
    While (IntPokemonCounter < 51)
        PokemonPics(IntPokemonCounter < 51) = My.Resources.(PokémonName(IntPokemonCounter) &".png")
        listPokemon.Items.Add(PokémonNumber(IntPokemonCounter) + PokémonName(IntPokemonCounter))
        'MsgBox("The " & IntPokemonCounter + 1 & "th pokemon is " & PokémonName(IntPokemonCounter))
        IntPokemonCounter += 1
    End While
End Sub
```

The problem I'm having is not being able to choose a picture out of the names loaded from the .txt file. The pictures are loaded into resources and I dont want to make 151 if statements for each Pokemon, this is mainly based off of big data.
When I place it like this, it says "Identifier expected", instead of accepting the variable used in this line

```
PokemonPics(IntPokemonCounter < 51) = My.Resources.(PokémonName(IntPokemonCounter) &".png")
```

Originally I was going to load the picture directly to the picturebox but I hoped the array might fix the problem, it did not. This is for my Final Project, I am re-creating pokemon Red in Visual basic 2008 express edition. Thank you so much for any help provided.

Comment: VS uses designers to create property getters for the resources you add.  So, a "GoldStar" image becomes `My.Resources.GoldStar` thru a prop created: `Friend ReadOnly Property GoldStar() As Bitmap`  so you cannot substitute vars for the prop name.  try `My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(bmpName)` this will return an `Object`, so you will have to cast it.

Comment: Thanks a ton, but I don't understand what you mean. When I cast it into a bmp, would I have problems with the image being a png? @Plutonix

Comment: `Bitmap`, in this case, is just the NET `Type`.  The pixel data format it contains will still be PNG or whatever.  There are not individual classes for BMP, JPG, GIF etc - the `Bitmap` or `Image` class can contain any of them.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the innacurate questions and stuff, this is my first time using this type of service, I'm astonished by the community. @Plutonix

Comment: One last question to get it working, how would you cast the picture into a bitmap, I did a little bit of research, but I cant get it to work @Plutonix